# CSS3 animation delay

Tags: css3, анимация

Что делать, если я использую отрицательное значение для CSS задержки перехода? Я ссылаюсь на демо здесь http://www.tutorialspark.com/css3Reference/CSS3_animation-delay_Property.php

Answer (score 1):

В чем, собственно, суть вопроса?

> Отрицательные задержки анимации
>
> Положительная задержка откладывает
> начало анимации на некоторое время. А
> отрицательная — начинает анимацию
> немедленно, но не с самого сначала, а
> со времени, указанного в задержке.
> Другими словами, начинает анимацию с
> какого-то момента внутри её цикла. Это
> позволяет применять анимацию к
> нескольким элементам со сдвигом фазы,
> изменяя лишь время задержки.

[**Трюки с CSS-анимациями: мгновенные изменения, отрицательные задержки, анимация transform-origin и другое**](http://habrahabr.ru/company/nordavind/blog/209462/)